# How to increase the default memory usage in odoo?

Tags: memory, odoo-8, ram, ubuntu-server

I'm using ubuntu server and configure the odoo project. it has 8GB of ram and available memory is arround 6GB so i need to increase the odoo default memory. So please let me know how to increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried playing with some of Odoo's Advanced and Multiprocessing options?

*odoo.py --help*

```
Advanced options:
    --osv-memory-count-limit=OSV_MEMORY_COUNT_LIMIT
                        Force a limit on the maximum number of records kept in
                        the virtual osv_memory tables. The default is False,
                        which means no count-based limit.
    --osv-memory-age-limit=OSV_MEMORY_AGE_LIMIT
                        Force a limit on the maximum age of records kept in
                        the virtual osv_memory tables. This is a decimal value
                        expressed in hours, and the default is 1 hour.
    --max-cron-threads=MAX_CRON_THREADS
                        Maximum number of threads processing concurrently cron
                        jobs (default 2).

  Multiprocessing options:
    --workers=WORKERS   Specify the number of workers, 0 disable prefork mode.
    --limit-memory-soft=LIMIT_MEMORY_SOFT
                        Maximum allowed virtual memory per worker, when
                        reached the worker be reset after the current request
                        (default 671088640 aka 640MB).
    --limit-memory-hard=LIMIT_MEMORY_HARD
                        Maximum allowed virtual memory per worker, when
                        reached, any memory allocation will fail (default
                        805306368 aka 768MB).
    --limit-time-cpu=LIMIT_TIME_CPU
                        Maximum allowed CPU time per request (default 60).
    --limit-time-real=LIMIT_TIME_REAL
                        Maximum allowed Real time per request (default 120).
    --limit-request=LIMIT_REQUEST
                        Maximum number of request to be processed per worker
                        (default 8192).
```

Also if you are using WSGI or something similar to run Odoo, these may also need some tuning.

Comment: limit-memory-hard = 640 * your workers (e.g 4) *1024 * 1024 = 2684354560