# Dump and Zip file can not resore odoo 8, how to solve it?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

**File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 757, in restore

```
data = base64.b64encode(db_file.read())
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 54, in b64encode

```
# Strip off the trailing newline MemoryErrorline MemoryError**
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs since the size of the database backup is larger than Odoo worker's current memory limit. Increase limit_memory_soft and limit_memory_hard values in the [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41395319/4417511), or restore the file directly in PostgreSQL by typing `createdb dbname` followed by `psql dbname < DBDump`.

Comment: we get only zip and dump format only how can i get .sql format

Comment: i am sorry for confusion `dbname.sql` is the dump,  I have updated the answer, the way we usually take a postgresql db dump is as `pg_dump dbname > dbdump.sql`  gives you the sql file.

Comment: how to restore dump into odoo gui? is it possible?